# Python __init__() issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee, falconframework

I have following classes; (I'm using peewee and falcon)

`models/Auth.py`:

```
from peewee import UUIDField, TextField

from models import BaseModel


class Auth(BaseModel):
    app_name = TextField()
    access_token = UUIDField()
```

`models/Tweet.py`:

```
from peewee import TextField

from models import BaseModel


class Tweet(BaseModel):
    username = TextField()
    message = TextField()
```

`models/__init__.py`:

```
from config import Database
from models.Auth import Auth
from models.BaseModel import BaseModel
from models.Tweet import Tweet

Database.connect()
Database.create_tables([Auth, Tweet], True)

"""
from config import Database
from models.BaseModel import BaseModel
from models.Tweet import Tweet
Database.connect()
Database.create_tables([Tweet], True)
"""
```

`models/BaseModel.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime

from peewee import DateTimeField
from playhouse.signals import pre_save, Model

from config import Database


class BaseModel(Model):
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        database = Database


@pre_save(sender=BaseModel)
def pre_save(sender, instance, created):
    if created:
        instance.updated_at = datetime.now()
```

Code piece that commented in `__init__.py` runs without error when I run `gunicorn --reload hyperion` but uncommented piece causes following error;

```
File "/Users/savaskoc/IdeaProjects/Hyperion/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models.Auth import Auth
File "/Users/savaskoc/IdeaProjects/Hyperion/models/Auth.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Auth(BaseModel):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I couldn't figure out where the error is. `Auth` and `Tweet` classes looks same...

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the `models.BaseModel` module where you need the `models.BaseModel.BaseModel` class in several places.

Comment: Auth and Tweet classes shares same import `from models import BaseModel`. Commented lines in `__init__` works, but uncommented not. The only difference is Auth class

Comment: By the way, it's a really bad idea to do anything in `__init__.py` that would shadow a submodule name, like `from models.Auth import Auth` or any of those other `from models.Whatever` imports you have there.

Comment: @user2357112 Do you have another idea for keep structure like package/class.py and use `from package import class`? I don't like something like `from models.Auth import Auth`

Comment: I would recommend just sticking your models in one file. This isn't Java; you don't need to limit yourself to one class per file, and attempts to make Python imports work like Java imports just lead to awkward code and bugs like what you're seeing here.

Comment: @user2357112 For models, its okay. What if I have complex classes in one file I think it can be mess eventually...

Btw. Problem solved when I merge all classes into one file